# Add tab bar for all the screens iOS(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am working with `UISplitViewController`. I have `UISplitViewController` which contain `UITabBarController`. So I want to display tab bar in all the screen through out the application (Even in detail screen of `UISplitViewController` for iPhone). Please see the approach:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use segue to move from one controller to another controller or move via navigation so in the next controller your  tabbar will be show
just like if u want to move from A to B Controller set stroyboard id ie "SecondVc"

```
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVc")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

or just make connection using storyboard